# Save and Rename file created from .xltm-excel-template while that (temporary) file is opened with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, save

My goal is to save and rename a file that was created from an .xl**t**m excel-template while that (temporary) file is opened with VBA and has not been saved before.

The workflow goes as follows:

1. User clicks on .xltm Excel-Template file in a folder, opening a new "copy" of that excel-template (but not the xltm excel-template itself)
2. The User then clicks a macro-button to import some data into the sheets of this file (e.g. from Access)
3. This file than should be saved and possibly renamed based on data contained in the sheet.

This situation differs from the following situations:

- Copying and renaming a simple excel-file (.xlsx)
- Copying and renaming an excel-file with macros (.xlsm)
- Copying and renaming an excel-file that is not opened (this would be done wits "Name As")

As stated, my situation is that I would like to save the excel-file, that was created as a new copy when a user has clicked on an .xltm file (excel-template with macros) in a folder and performed some macros in this temporary file.

After opening the new copy of the template I ran the following sub to save this new copy as an xlsm.file with the name "Test" in the downloads folder, but had an 1004 error:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\Test.xlsm"
```

In some forums, it is stated that "ActiveWorkbook" cannot be used in this case, as the actual file where the code is run is stored as a tmp.file in the Windows Temp folder. And at this point in time, it is not a workbook, so the relative path "Active Workbook" would not work.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the code performing the save in the workbook to be saved?  If so then try `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Have you tried this: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\USERNAME\Downloads\Test", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled ?

Answer (score 0):

### A Template Workbook Exercise

- Copy the code into a new workbook. Adjust the paths in both procedures, e.g. `C:\Test`. Now add two buttons (or not) and assign the two procedures to them. Save the file anywhere.
- Now run the `createTemplate` procedure and it will save this file as a template named `MyTemplate.xltm`, close it and open the folder (`in Windows Explorer`) where it has been saved. Now in the folder double-click the newly created file and it will open as `MyTemplate1` (a copy of the template).
- Now run the `testTemplate` procedure and it will write the current time (a time stamp) to cell `A1` before it gets saved as `TestTemplate.xlsm` and closed. Again it navigates to the folder in `Windows Explorer`.
- Now you can open this newly created file to see the previously written time stamp in cell `A1`.
- Note that the template file has the `xltm` extension while the last (resulting) file has the `xlsm` extension.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createTemplate()
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\65185447"
    With ThisWorkbook
        .SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & "MyTemplate", xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
        .FollowHyperlink FolderPath
        .Close
    End With
End Sub

Sub testTemplate()
    Const FolderPath As String = "F:\Test\2020\65185447"
    Range("A1") = Now
    Columns("A").AutoFit
    With ThisWorkbook
        .SaveAs FolderPath & "\" & "TestTemplate", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        .FollowHyperlink FolderPath
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you! A follow-up question: Rather than writing the executing code in a new extra workbook, is it possible that the code runs when a user clicks on the file in Windows Explorer? The workflow would be: 1. User clicks on xltm.file containing all code. 2. A copy of the xltm-file opens. 3. The user clicks on some buttons in the file, running some subroutines, e.g. import data from Access into a sheet. 4. The user then clicks a button on the currently open sheet to save the currently open workbook as an xlsm-file. If possible, the file should have a name based on info contained in the sheet.

Comment: This is material for another question. Use this, add some more info, and add the code, and that's it. You can post a link to it in the comments to inform me to take a look if you please. It's always better to have multiple opinions (solutions) though. The important part is that you have to put the code into the workbook (probably the template) containing the button.